# playing multiple rtsp video streams in same activity

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, rtsp

i want to play multiple rtsp streams in a android(at least 8) app at the same time and view them in a main activity.

i was able to play 3 streams at a time using videoviews which were already defined in the layout.
but i want to add videoviews dynamincally(when a listview item is clicked). can someone give an example of how to play these streams in new threads, because i am not able to figure out how to use threads for streaming videos.

And what should be the base layout for the videoviews.

I am actually inspired by the milestone xprotect app and want to play videos like they do. Any ideas on how they do it ??

**Milstone app playing multiple streams**

[image]

Comment: Are you using any library? If not refer vitamio

Comment: @RIT i am not using any Library. I am using Android's VideoView. Do you have any ideas on how Milestone is doing it or can you point me   how should i go in building such a app.

Comment: @RIT I have no problem in playing rtsp stream, i just want to know how to create such dynamic layout based on users interaction who can add or delete streams to play. And how do i play each stream in seperate thread or something so that it dosenot hang the main ui.